# nforce org.getUrl(url,cb) - value of url

Tags: rest, node.js, node-salesforce, nforce

I have a Node app running on heroku where I am using the nforce lib. I received
{ Error: Could not find a match for URL error.} while using org.getUrl from nforce library.
For the url string, I have used the same url that I was hitting through workbench(i.e something like this : "/services/apexrest/namespace/restresourcexyz").
Should I enter the entire URL here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relative URI is the correct argument. Two possibilities:

1. Your REST resource does not have a GET method
2. The URI resolution on SF side is case-sensitive. Either the name of the namespace and/or the name of the resource do not match what you have in the URI

Comment: Got the issue. Namespace was in lower case. Thanks for the quick response.